# how to restore the original window intellij layout

Tags: layout, intellij-idea

Instead of choosing 'Restore default layout' I mistakenly choosed 'Store current as default layout', so my current layout (which I don't want to use) is set as default.

Now I cannot go to original layout anymore. Is there a way to reset the layout to its shipped value?

I'm on intellij 12.1.1, on Windows7.

Comment: For posterity... if you want to save the layout, the "Store Current Layout as Default" button is under "Window" in the menu bar.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Layout stores the position and state of the tool windows, you can change it back how you like it and store it as the new default.

There is no GUI to reset layout to the IDE default, but the configuration is stored inside the project directory in `./idea/workspace.xml` file. When the project is closed you can delete `<component name="ToolWindowManager">` node from this file.

Comment: this did not do anything but close all open tabs for me on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: That configuration seems to be found now in <projectname>.iws file instead.

Answer (score 1):

To anyone who is struggling with this "basic" error, you can go to **Settings (Ctrl + Alt + S) -> Appearance & Behavior -> Appearance -> Tool Windows** and check the following check boxes:

- Show tool window bars
- Show tool window numbers (optional)

All the others solutions that I have found didn't solve the problem and it is very frustrating that the IDE does not give support to reset the Window to its default.

P.S.: I can't post a screenshot of the settings mentioned above due to security of my company laptop, but it is very easy to find following the path I have written.