# detached android monitor window in android studio 2.1

Tags: android, user-interface, android-studio

I just upgraded android studio from 1.5 to 2.1.

Then I could not see any logcat messages in the android monitor window.

I have poor vision and somehow managed to detach the android monitor window.

Now the logcat messages are appearing in the window.

Is there any way to reset it back where is usually hangs out?

edit: i managed to get it pinned and docked. but it takes up the whole width of the ide.

Thanks

Comment: you can restart logcat window with restart button at left bottom in logcat.

Comment: the logcat messages are in the window, but it's still detached.

Comment: now lot's of windows are detached. putting the back makes things worse.

Comment: have you tried restart adb server?

Comment: If I understand correctly, see if this helps.  https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/viewing-modes.html?origin=old_help

Comment: @panda problem survives reboot.

Comment: @cricket_007 i have been fooling around with that, but i can't get the windows back where they were.

Comment: Try this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189517/how-to-restore-the-original-window-intellij-layout

Comment: @cricket_007 ... the configuration is stored inside the project directory in ./idea/workspace.xml file. When the project is closed you can delete <component name="ToolWindowManager"> node from this file. - worked, post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Android Studio is just a rebranded IntelliJ IDEA, the same answer applies as [How to restore the original window IntelliJ layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189517/how-to-restore-the-original-window-intellij-layout).

> The configuration is stored inside the project directory in `./idea/workspace.xml` file. When the project is closed you can delete `<component name="ToolWindowManager">` node from this file.